# Redux store is filled with a bunch of strange properties

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been using Redux for my project to store the application state, and until now it was working as expected. Then, I came to a stage where I needed to persist the store state across the app, and after looking online I tried integrating **react-persist** library.

The integration seems went well, and the store state is now persisted in the app.

**HOWEVER**, when I go to check out the store state in the **redux dev in the browser** I see a whole bunch of properties that I do not recognize AT ALL, and I do not see the slices that I created. I also see a bunch of unknown actions dispatched and when I dispatch my own action it does not show up in the actions list, but again, the app works perfect as I expect it to

This worries me because I used this dev tool very often to make the app work, but for future updates, I don't know how to debug.

Here is a screenshot of what the current store looks like in the dev tool.

[image]

I am not sure if any of the code would be useful, as I have no clue which part of the code could be a result of this. If you need to see a piece of code, I can add it upon request. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself that the issue was that while integrating **redux-persist** I switched from **configureStore()** to **createStore()** (not sure if I could still keep it that way, but the library's example was with createStore()), and I did not add **window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE**** to the store.

So, the code I added was

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
```

and, passed this `composeEnhancers` to the `createStore()` like this:

```
export default  createStore(persistedReducer, composeEnhancers());
```

Comment: You can use redux-persist just as well with configureStore. You should probably not use createStore directly nowadays.

Comment: any guide on how to set up the store with redux-persist and configureStore? All of the examples I found were a couple years old and were all using createStore

Comment: Not really any different. The only thing you have to know is that you can also pass a reducer into the `reducer` option of `configureStore`, it does not need to be an object of  reducers. So just pass your `persistedReducer` in there.